# Removing pinned chrome shortcut from taskbar using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to uninstall chrome and remove the shortcuts using a powershell script but the chrome icon is staying on the taskbar even after being removed from appdata\microsoft\internet explorer\quick launch\userpinned\taskbar\

This is the code I have which removes the shortcut from the taskbar folder but the shortcut is still appearing. After force closing the taskbar and re-opening, the icon has changed from a chrome icon to a blank file icon. Is there a way to remove this blank file icon? Thanks

```
$taskbarPath1 = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($env:APPDATA, "Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\Google Chrome.lnk")

if (Test-Path $taskbarPath1) {
    Remove-Item $taskbarPath1 -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Write-Host "Chrome shortcut removed from taskbar"
} else {
    Write-Host "Chrome shortcut not found on taskbar"
}

Stop-Process -ProcessName explorer -Force
Start-Process explorer
```

Comment: Just an aside: You can simplify the path string to `"$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\Google Chrome.lnk"` (or `Join-Path $env:APPDATA '\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\Google Chrome.lnk'`)